# Как отправить данные в нормальной кодировке?

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Добрый вечер. Посылаю `GET` запросом в базу данных такой ссылкой

```
http://192.168.1.134/addItem.php?name=Славные парни&plc=ул. Кутузова, д.11А&prc=196&lplc=111&type=Детское&web=mcc.org&time=11.13.16 10:40&minfo=Что бывает, когда напарником брутального костолома становится субтильный лопух? Наемный охранник Джексон Хили и частный детектив Холланд Марч вынуждены работать в паре, чтобы распутать плевое дело о пропавшей девушке, которое оборачивается преступлением века.&img=http://www.kinopoisk.ru/images/film_big/841152.jpg&sinfo=Что бывает, когда напарником брутального костолома становится субтильный лопух?
```

При этом в базу они приходят в неправильной кодировке. Кодировка mysql таблицы - `ut8_general_ci`

Как сделать так, чтобы данные передавались в нормальной кодировке?

Comment: Что такое "нормальная" кодировка? Покажите что приходит.

Comment: Что находится в скрипте addItem.php? В каком виде данные сохраняются в базу данных MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После соединения с базой данных попробуйте использовать [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php).

Так же можно в phpmyadmin после выбора базы данных, выполнить: 

**show variables like 'char%';**

Результатом будет таблица типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может у вас база в одной кодировке а таблица в другой, поэтому проблемы и возникают.